# How can I combine/nest EnumFields in Django?

Tags: python, django, enums

[Django-EnumFields](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-enumfields/0.1.2) lets you combine Enum fields in Django (the clue was in the title).

Can you combine nest these?

Here's an example that plays off the [docs](https://github.com/5monkeys/django-enumfield):

```
from django.db import models
from django_enumfield import enum

class BeerStyle(enum.Enum):
    LAGER = 0
    STOUT = 1
    WEISSBIER = 2

class SoftDrinkStyle(enum.Enum):
    COKE = 3
    LEMONADE = 4

class Drink(models.Model):
    style = enum.EnumField(????, default=BeerStyle.LAGER)
```

I don't know what would go in place of `????`, or if there is a better way to get this nested/combination to play out with Django. I'm mainly asking as I want Enum behaviour, with the ability to probe different types, e.g. in a save method, check for `User` age if the Drink is or type `Beer`.

Is this possible? Having played with this for a bit I don't see how.

Comment: If `Drink` needs age limits and other behaviour, why don't you just use a Model instead? It seems like Enum is not the right tool to use here.

Comment: @HåkenLid because the example I give is not actually a good representation of what I have. I am convinced I want enums in my example as the choices it provides will never change or grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked over how Python Enums work, this looks like the best behaviour to mock up 'subclasses'

```
from django.db import models
from django_enumfield import enum

class DrinkStyle(enum.Enum):
    LAGER = (0, 'Beer')
    STOUT = (1, 'Beer')
    WEISSBIER = (2, 'Beer')
    COKE = (3, 'SoftDrink')
    LEMONADE = (4, 'SoftDrink')

    def __init__(self, id, drink_type):
        self.id = id    
        self.type = drink_type

    @property
    def type(self):
        return self.drink_type

class Drink(models.Model):
    style = enum.EnumField(DrinkStyle, default=DrinkStyle.LAGER)
```

Then use `DrinkStyle.COKE.type` to return the type.

Comment: Turns out this doesn't work with the library I have. The general idea works,  though the implementation would be messier.

Comment: which library did you use @pureferret

Comment: @dejell I didn't in the end.